How do I add camera live streaming on my transmitter from the camera on the plane?
I'm a newbie in RC Airplanes and have bought the AL37 Airliner and installed everything right. What I didn't know was how do I add a camera to the plane which gives a live streaming view to the transmitters screen. I have a this transmitter and receiver which does not support LED screen, but has LCD screen.So, I had 2 main questions:

How do I broadcast the camera's recording to the transmitter screen in live?
Which transmitter can do this job(in India) as I was unable to find any such transmitter which supports LED display screen?

